# Kinesis Advantage2 Windows Menu Key

Tags: keyboard, kinesis-advantage

According to the user manual I should be able to access the Menu Key by first pressing the Keypad button 
[page 14](https://kinesis-ergo.com/wp-content/uploads/kb500-user_manual.pdf). I think maybe the user manual is out of date.

The only thing that happens is the volume keys alternate to other functions like scroll lock.

How do I get to the context menu (Menu Key) button in windows mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm actually an idiot..the correct user manual for Advantage2 is https://kinesis-ergo.com/wp-content/uploads/Adv2-Users-Manual-5-3-19_us.pdf [Page 37]

For QWERTY & Dvorak, it is <kbd>keypad</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>